# Previous Month and Current Month

Tags: business-objects, webi

I'm new in the WEBI report in SAP BusinessObjects and I need to create a variable in the Month(Int) and Year(int) that the output of the report shows the current month and previous month.

For example it should show the Month of January as previous month and February as current month. But it will not show all the previous months like December previous year. Thank you for the help

Comment: What version of BusinessObjects are you on? What is your underlying database (e.g., Oracle, SQL Server, or something else)? Can you describe your data more fully? What do you have to filter against for the the previous and current month?